# How can I store Google Analytics conversion code?

Tags: google-analytics

So let me rephrase and give a bit more detail. So basically I have a single site but I run the site in a production and UAT environment, separately. The production website uses Google Analytics and the UAT does not and my current development workflow is dev -> uat -> production. I do not want the analytics to be active for UAT, so I have a choice of either removing the script tags when the site is moved from uat to production or to build logic that will render the scripts when the Google Analytics is required.

Comment: What do you mean by 'storing the tracking code'?

Comment: Set a domain exclude filter on your analytics account and filter out visits from your testdomain. That way you don't need to change anything on your staging code (plus you can test your analytics code in staging).

Answer (score 0):

I don’t understand  your request, but if you are going to install the tracking code Past all your tags to the production website. You can use manual tagging or Google Tag Manager.